# Are named functions good practice for jsx props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have an array of divs generated by javascript that should all have their own onClick function passed in I can easily use an arrow function to make them all behave in the way I would want. But ESLint highlights this as bad practice, no arrow functions or binds or even regular functions if all the flags are turned on. So here is a workaround I have been doing and I'm wondering if it is good practice or if I'm merely fooling my linter without getting any benefit?

So if I do this:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3]

array.map((d, index) => {
  return <div onClick = {
    () => myGeneralMethodOrFunction(index)
  }
  />
})
```

It may seem neat but triggers my linter so instead I do this:

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3]

array.map((d, index) => {
  function onThisClick() {
    myGeneralMethodOrFunction(index)
  }
  return <div onClick = {onThisClick}/>
})
```

And I'm just not sure if the named function makes any difference towards actually making the problem my linter is trying to make me address go away (which is that arrow functions and such creates unnecessary re-rendering)

This seems especially fishy when you consider that writing onThisClick() directly into the divs onClick={} will trigger the linter as well, even though I don't how that is different from what I'm doing.

This is the error I'm talking about: https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Thoughts?

Comment: Linter isn't always right. In this case, choose whatever style you want but *stick with it*.

Comment: what is the linting error exactly?

Comment: @DavinTryon https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-no-bind.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason probably being, anonymous functions are created each time the render is executed and named functions are not.
While this is not a big deal, it's considered to be neat and good practice in the React community.

Check this wonderful article for more on the topic https://medium.com/@rjun07a/binding-callbacks-in-react-components-9133c0b396c6

You can try the code below.

```
const array = [0, 1, 2, 3]

class Example extends React.Component {

  // Method currying with extra bound variable from callbacks
  onThisClick = (index) => (event) => {
    // Your execution on index which you send in render method
  }

  render() {
    return(
      array.map((d, index) => (
         <div 
          key={index}
          onClick={this.onThisClick(index)}
         />
        )
      )
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: And the onClick will be a stored function instead of being called? That's my issue with passing in (index) as an argument, but is there something magical about the way you made the method with an arrow function?

(in my example I write onClick={onThisClick} not onThisClick() for this reason, with the () it gets called not stored)

Comment: Yes if you check `onThisClick` can only be invoked when you do `onThisClick(index)(event)` because it is a function that returns a function. So, you are basically passing a function to onClick by only sending `onThisClick(index)` which returns a function. This is the method currying strategy.

Comment: That's exactly what I need! Thank you Nandu :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Try reading through that article I linked, it will be very helpful.

Comment: This will also create new functions each time render is called, though. It looks nicer, and the linter will shut up because it's not capable of understanding that functions are still being created. But the original performance "problem", if you can call it that, is still there.